# count all specific words that ended in each line

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, grep, perl

how to count all words that ended with ".wsp" in the file

```
more file
/application_1532998892988_0207/driver/BlockManager/memory/remainingOffHeapMem_MB.wsp
/spark/application_1532998892988_0207/driver/BlockManager/memory/memUsed_MB.wsp
```

meanwhile, I create this syntax

```
 sed s'/\// / g' file   | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -o '.wsp' | wc -l
```

but this syntax isn't so elegant

Comment: I mean to count the words .wsp that ended on each line ( only if they ended )

Comment: I want to count only the ".wsp" words that ended in the line  , if ".wsp" not ended in the line then no need to count it

Comment: The title should have been the reverse: "Count the lines that ended in a specific word"....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
 grep -c '\.wsp$' file
```

- `-c`  count of matching lines for each input file